# $A$ is singular and normal matrix, what must be its characteristic polynomial?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A$ be a $5\times5$ real singular matrix which is normal. If $1-2i$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ and $2+i$ is an eigenvalue of $A^*$ (conjugate transpose), what must be its characteristic polynomial?

Since $A$ is singular, $0$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ and $1-2i$, $2-i$ (eigenvalues of $A$ are conjugates of eigenvalues of $A^*$). Can I determine algebraic multiplicities of these eigenvalues or if there are other eigenvalues how do I find them? 
**Update**: From the comments 1+2i, 2+i are also eigenvalues but why?

Comment: Hint: since $A$ is real, its characteristic polynomial has real coefficients. Thus, the roots of this polynomial are either real or come in complex conjugate pairs.

Comment: So you mean 1+2i and 2+i are also eigenvalues?

Comment: @rackne that's correct. What degree must the characteristic polynomial be? Do you see how this answers your question?

Comment: @CameronWilliams yes there are now 5 eigenvalues but I'm having difficulties to understand why they should come in cojugate pairs.

Comment: Since $A$ is a real matrix, its characteristic polynomial has only real coefficients. For a polynomial with real coefficients, the roots come in complex conjugate pairs. To see why this is the case, take a complex conjugate of the entire equation. The coefficients are all real so they don't change. All that changes is that $x$ goes to $\bar{x} $.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $p$ is a polynomial with real coefficients and $p(a+bi)=0$, then it is the case that $p(a-bi)=0$. Here, the characteristic polynomial of $A$ has real coefficients, so it immediately follows that $1+2i$ and $2+i$ are also roots of the characteristic polynomial.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I don't really understand why $p(a+bi)=0$ implies $p(a-bi)=0$

Comment: @rackne assume that $p(z) = \sum_{k=0}^{n} a_k z^k$, substitute $z = x + i y$, group real and imaginary terms together. Since $p(z) = 0$, both real and imaginary parts of $p(z)$ are zero. Substitute $z = x - i y$, look at how the result differs from $p(x + i y)$ and conclude.
Alternativelly, use the fact that complex conjugation is an automorphism of $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: @lisyarus that's a really mistaken way of doing it. Expanding will only cause headaches. Just take a complex conjugate of your equation $p(z) =0$ where you've substituted your general expression for the polynomial. Also conjugation being an automorphism doesn't really help here..

Comment: If $z \in \mathbb{C}$ is so that $p(z)=0$, then $p(\overline{z})=\overline{p(z)}=\overline{0}=0$.

Comment: @CameronWilliams the fact that $p(\overline{z})=\overline{p(z)}$ for any $p \in \mathbb{R}[z]$ is equivalent to complex conjugation being an automorphism fixing $\mathbb{R}$, IIRC.

Comment: @lisyarus I know this but I meant those terms aren't helpful here.

Comment: @CameronWilliams why not helpful? It proves the claim. If $p(\overline{z})=\overline{p(z)}$, then $p(a-ib)=p(\overline{a+ib})=\overline{p(a+ib)}=\overline{0}=0$.